# upgrading to express 4 passport stopped working

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am upgrading the express 4 and my passport is failing every time now.  It is not even logging to the console in passport.use(new LocalStrategy.

It redirects the /failure every time without hitting any breakpoints

```
// Use the LocalStrategy within Passport.
//   Strategies in passport require a `verify` function, which accept
//   credentials (in this case, a username and password), and invoke a callback
//   with a user object.  In the real world, this would query a database;
//   however, in this example we are using a baked-in set of users.
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        console.log("LocalStrategy working...");
        // asynchronous verification, for effect...
        process.nextTick(function() {

            // Find the user by username.  If there is no user with the given
            // username, or the password is not correct, set the user to `false` to
            // indicate failure and set a flash message.  Otherwise, return the
            // authenticated `user`.
            findByUsername(username, password, function(err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    return done(err);
                }
                if (!user) {
                    return done(null, false, {
                        message: 'Unknown user ' + username
                    });
                } else {
                    return done(null, user);
                }

            })

        });
    }
));

app.use(cookieParser('keyboard cat'));
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));

// Initialize Passport!  Also use passport.session() middleware, to support
// persistent login sessions (recommended).
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
        failureRedirect: '/failure',
        failureFlash: false
    }),
    function(req, res) {
        res.cookie('userdata', req.user);
        switch (req.user.role) {
            case 'candidate':
                res.redirect('/app/candidates');
                break;
            case 'employer':
                res.redirect('/app/employers');
                break;
            case 'provider':
                res.redirect('/app/providers');
                break;
            case 'admin':
                res.redirect('/app/admin');
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have all relevant code included the reason for the failure is likely missing body parser. The authentication strategy will try to find the username and password fields from `req.body` and `req.query`, and if there is no body parser used `req.body` will be empty. The strategy will then [fail straight away](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/33d420ba5f54939c85adc5e4b61009db6467a900/lib/strategy.js#L71-L76) as it would have nothing to pass to your verify callback.

You need to make the Express application use relevant body parser, for example:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

Comment: This was there but below my routes and apparently has to be called before the passport initialize and session stuff.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you included LocalStrategy?

```
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;

app.use(express.cookieParser()); // read cookies 
app.use(express.bodyParser()); // get information from html forms
```